# CSS gradient not working on Android 2.3.6?

Tags: android, css, cross-browser, mobile-website

I'm using this code for a `div`

```
background: url(../img/texturee.png), linear-gradient(left, #de2785 1%,#f954b1 50%,#de2785 100%);
```

and to add vendor prefixes I'm using this library http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree/

It's working fine in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, iPhone, iPad but not in Android 2.3.6 default browser. Am i doing something wrong?

http://caniuse.com/#search=gradients

**Edit:**

After @mdmullinax answer I changed it to

```
background: url(../img/texturee.png), -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #de2785 1%,#f954b1 50%,#de2785 100%);
```

but still not working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

possible you'll need to use the outdated gradient syntax...`-webkit-gradient`

[Surfin' Safari - Blog Archive » Introducing CSS Gradients](http://www.webkit.org/blog/175/introducing-css-gradients/) - documentation on outdated syntax

[Surfin' Safari - Blog Archive » CSS3 Gradients](http://www.webkit.org/blog/1424/css3-gradients/) - see the paragraph on `Changes from -webkit-gradient`

caniuse.com briefly notes this

> Note: Partial support in Safari/Chrome refers to requiring an outdated gradient syntax to work

but doesn't provide any additional details

**EDIT:**

perhaps try

```
/* bkgd w/outdated webkit gradient */
background: url(../img/texturee.png), 
            -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(1%,#de2785), color-stop(50%,#f954b1), color-stop(100%,#de2785));
/* bkgd w/standards gradient */
background: url(../img/texturee.png), 
            linear-gradient(left, #de2785 1%,#f954b1 50%,#de2785 100%);
```

Comment: But I'm using this library http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree/ which adds vendor prefix whenever required.

Comment: it will add vendor prefixes but I don't see that it has support for outdated syntax, we're talking a difference of the standard `-webkit-linear-gradient` vs outdated `-webkit-gradient`, I don't believe prefixfree will know to also apply the `-webkit-gradient` style since it's a different syntax.